# symfony assets are 404ing through app_dev.php

Tags: symfony, nginx, assetic

I'm trying to get an existing site running locally in the vagrant environment it was provided to me in. However, CSS assets are 404ing.

`app/config/config_dev.yml` has:

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
    write_to: "/%kernel.root_dir%/../web/"
```

I've done:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink
php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev
```

The output from both commands looks as expected and I can SEE the generated files in `/web/css/`

When I visit the local site though, I get a 404 on:

http://192.168.33.10/app_dev.php/css/59addc3_main_1.css

If I manually edit this to be:

http://192.168.33.10/css/59addc3_main_1.css

The CSS file loads.

Is this an issue with the Nginx conf rather than Symfony? My full vhost conf looks like:

```
server {
  listen                *:80 default_server;

  server_name           www.mysite.dev;

  root '/vagrant/web';

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;

  location ^~ /javascript {

    default_type text/plain;
    return 410 "d14:failure reason13:not a tracker8:retry in5:nevere";
  }
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ {

    expires 30d;
  }
  location ~* \.(js|css)$ {

    expires 30d;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml text/css text/js text/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json application/xml+rss application/javascript;
  }
  location / {

    try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
  }
  location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|app_test|config)\.php(/|$) {

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

}
```

Comment: You're right, this is a nginx config issue. Ideally, you'd want your app to serve static files out of a static folder, so your URLs need to be configured correctly in your app. Then you'd have a `location ^~ /static/ { ... }` with `alias /web/css/`. Since this is not the case, you could hardcode it for `app_dev.php/css`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm still unclear on why it's failing though. My nginx conf doesn't look significantly different to the suggested one at http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx - to my eyes, at least. It certainly makes no mention of aliasing static assets dirs. Why will the recommended conf work, when mine does not?

Comment: Ah, there is a subtle difference. Do you have the `location / { try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args; }` block in your conf as well?

Comment: @KeenanLawrence Ah, really? I appear to have a similar line, although it's pointing at `app_dev.php`. I've amended my post to include the full vhost conf - is that the issue? It should just be pointing to `app.php`, even on dev?

Comment: I speak under correction. Thanks for updating the post. It looks fine. Where's your `fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;` though? In any case you can tweak your (js|css) block to serve these requests from the desired location.

Comment: Good point, although I tried adding that line and it doesn't seem to have fixed it.... I think I'm going to see if I can get access to the dev server to have a look what's actually on it. I can't see how this codebase would result in a functioning site, and rather than try to debug what may well be outdated code I'll just find out what they're *actually* running and use that. Thanks very much for your help, though.